# neo4j: shortest paths constrained by node and rel properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

From the tutorial:

```
MATCH p=shortestPath( (keanu:Person)-[:KNOWS*]-(kevin:Person) ) 
WHERE keanu.name="Keanu Reeves" and kevin.name = "Kevin Bacon"
RETURN length(p)
```

Imagine each Person node has an age property and an occupation.  Every KNOWS edge has a `length of acquaintance` property.

What Cypher query would return a shortest path with, for instance,

```
age > 40 years
not (occupation = ACTOR)
lengthOfAcquaintance > 10 years
```

In molecular biology interaction data, we wish to make yet more complex queries - probably of the sort which cypher handles well, but just how eludes me. For example:

Find the shortest paths between receptor molecule A and transcription factor B, where most edges are from small-scale experiments, most of the genes are annotated as kinase, and evidence (weight) for the edges is `greater than 0.5`

These queries probably come up in lots of settings. Can anyone point me towards readings and examples which will help me understand how this is done?  And maybe provide a modest extension of the "Bacon Number" query which accommodates one node and one edge property?

Thanks!

- Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is the [ALL predicate](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-predicates.html#functions-all).

Here are a couple of examples using it :

ShortestPath where all actors in the paths should have an `age > 40` :

```
MATCH p=shortestPath( (keanu:Person)-[:KNOWS*]-(kevin:Person) ) 
WHERE keanu.name = "Keanu Reeves"
AND kevin.name = "Kevin Bacon" 
AND ALL(x IN nodes(p) WHERE x.age > 40)
RETURN p
```

ShortestPath where all edges should have a `lengthOfAcquaintance > 10`

```
MATCH p=shortestPath( (keanu:Person)-[:KNOWS*]-(kevin:Person) ) 
WHERE keanu.name = "Keanu Reeves" 
AND kevin.name = "Kevin Bacon"
AND ALL(x in rels(p) WHERE x.lengthOfAcquaintance > 100
RETURN p
```

Of course you can combine the both :

```
MATCH p=shortestPath( (keanu:Person)-[:KNOWS*]-(kevin:Person) ) 
WHERE keanu.name = "Keanu Reeves" 
AND kevin.name = "Kevin Bacon"
AND ALL(x in rels(p) WHERE x.lengthOfAcquaintance > 10)
AND ALL(x in nodes(p) WHERE x.age > 40)
RETURN p
```

Comment: Many thanks, Christophe!  An elegant solution,  beautifully presented.